# How many time React should render?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rendering

I wrote a simple React to test how React render

```js
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const App = (props) => {
  // State
  const [trackIndex, setTrackIndex] = useState(1);
  const [trackProgress, setTrackProgress] = useState(0);
  const clickHandler = () =>{
       setTrackIndex((trackIndex)=>trackIndex+1)
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("effect; trackIndex=",trackIndex)
    console.log("effect; trackProgress=",trackProgress)
    if(trackIndex<5){
      console.log("set trackProgress")
      setTrackProgress(trackIndex)
    }
  });

  console.log("render")

  return (
    <div>
      <p>{trackIndex}</p>
      <p>{trackProgress}</p>
      <button onClick={clickHandler}>Click me</button>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
document.getElementById('root')
);
```

The following is the console output:

```
render
effect; trackIndex= 1
effect; trackProgress= 0
set trackProgress
render
effect; trackIndex= 1
effect; trackProgress= 1
set trackProgress
render
```

It seems that React renders three times before I click the button. The last rendering really confuses me. Could anyone explain to me why this render occurs and why no effect runs after this rendering? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your `useEffect` is setting the state with the `setTrackProgress` on the initial render of the component. This is because `trackIndex` starts at `1` which is lower than 5. (seen by the `if(trackIndex<5)`) Notice that you haven't provided array dependency to `useEffect` as the second parameter. According to [react-documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect) this means the effect will only occur once after the first initial render of the component.

Also, I would suggest adding `useCallback` to your `clickHandler` in order to prevent re-defining the function for every render. (According to [react-documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback))

Answer (score 0):

You're practically making an infinite loop, but React saves you. The first `render` log is the initial render, then the `useEffect` is executed and your component re-renders, leading to the 2nd `render` log and the first `effect; ...` log. Now a 2nd `useEffect` is executed. However, the value of `trackIndex` hasn't changed, so your if statement will evaluate true and updates `trackProgress` with the same state/value(1). This leads to another re-render and the third `render` log. Now, you would think that a 3rd `useEffect` would be executed, but React is smart enough to know when state hasn't changed and thus doesn't execute the `useEffect`.

Add dependencies to your `useEffect` as stated above. That'll solve your problem.

```
useEffect(
  ...
, [trackIndex])
```